# Split an array-object without replication

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I'm learning how to handle js arrays and I was wondering if it's possible to create new array-objects by splitting an attribute of an existing object.

I tried to do that with .map and .flatMap, but the output gives me combinations of objects that replicate the other values, while I'm looking for unique objects

I think that the code can be more clear:

```
const array=[ 
    { names:['something1', 'something2'],
      state:false,
      features:['feature1','feature2']
    },
    { names:['something3', 'something4'],
      state:true,
      features:['feature3','feature4']
    },
  ]

  array.flatMap(({names,state,features}) => {
    names.flatMap(name => {
      features.flatMap(feature => {
        console.log(({name,state,feature}));
      })
    })
  })
```

So, with this code the output is:

```
{ name: 'something1', state: false, feature: 'feature1' }
{ name: 'something1', state: false, feature: 'feature2' }
{ name: 'something2', state: false, feature: 'feature1' }
{ name: 'something2', state: false, feature: 'feature2' }
{ name: 'something3', state: true, feature: 'feature3' }
{ name: 'something3', state: true, feature: 'feature4' }
{ name: 'something4', state: true, feature: 'feature3' }
{ name: 'something4', state: true, feature: 'feature4' }
```

But I want the output to be:

```
{ name: 'something1', state: false, feature: 'feature1' },
{ name: 'something2', state: false, feature: 'feature2' },
{ name: 'something3', state: true, feature: 'feature3' },
{ name: 'something4', state: true, feature: 'feature4' }
```

I'm a newbie in coding, sorry if my words are not properly correct in describing this problem.
Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, slight edit on last one. Just map names.

```js
const arr = [{
  names: ["test1", "test2"],
  values: ["t1", "t2"]
},
{
  names: ["test3", "test4"],
  values: ["t3", "t4"]
}];

const flat = arr.reduce((a, {names, values}) => {
   names.map((name, i) => {   
     a.push({ name, value: values[i]});
  });
  return a;
}, []).flat();

console.log(`Flat: ${JSON.stringify(flat)}`);
```

Comment: Ok, sorry your desired output is confusing.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that this code gives the same output as mine, while I'm looking for the output in the last code-box

Comment: Corrected to reflect what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.flatMap()` with an inner `.map()` function (instead of a `.flatMap()` like you are doing) to map each element in the `names` array to its own respective object with it's associated `feature`.

See example below:

```js
const array = [{
    names: ['something1', 'something2'],
    state: false,
    features: ['feature1', 'feature2']
  },
  {
    names: ['something3', 'something4'],
    state: true,
    features: ['feature3', 'feature4']
  },
];

const res = array.flatMap(
  ({names, state, features}) => names.map((name, i) => ({name, state, feature: features[i]}))
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn programming, the magics might not be the best pick. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the like are algorithms themselves. The basics would be completing these tasks with simple loops (`for`, `while`) and sometimes recursion (like the general solution for the origin of this question).

What you have at the moment is an array, which you can iterate over in an `outer` loop, and inside there are objects with parallel arrays, which you could iterate over also, in an `inner` loop:

```js
const array=[ 
    { names:['something1', 'something2'],
      state:false,
      features:['feature1','feature2']
    },
    { names:['something3', 'something4'],
      state:true,
      features:['feature3','feature4']
    },
  ];
  
for(let outer=0;outer<array.length;outer++){
  let obj=array[outer];
  for(let inner=0;inner<obj.names.length;inner++)
    console.log({
      name:obj.names[inner],
      state:obj.state,
      feature:obj.features[inner]
    });
}
```

Then yes, the outer loop does not need the index at all, so it could directly iterate over the elements (`for(let obj of array)` or `array.forEach()`), but for the `inner` loop you need the index, so it is not that trivial to throw it away (see the strange inbalance with the suggested `map()` variants: they have `name`, and `features[i]` - where of course `name` is actually `names[i]` extracted already, but it hides a bit of the fact that the two arrays are traversed in parallel).